# Do you prototype mobile touch games on the desktop with mouse input? What tricks do you use?

Tags: xna, mobile, touch, prototyping

So I've been prototyping games that if completed would be mobile apps most likely.

But, I'm developing them in XNA on the desktop because its the environment I like the most.

I know I could target windows phone and be testing the touch interface rapidly on that device but I don't own one and I imagine the build and deploy to the phone loop slows you down a bit.

Does anyone else prototype games that would eventually use a touch interface using mouse controls initially?

What tricks do you use to ensure that it will eventually translate well when you move to touch controls?

Comment: Do you have the WP7 emulator? Its treats mouse input like touch input. Of course gestures and multitouch still requires a phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a WP7 and only a desktop computer the best solution is to use the WP7 Emulator. You can find more informations here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402563(v=vs.92).aspx

If you have installed the latest version of XNA, the WP7 emulator is installed at the same time. If you don't have it, you can get it from here:

http://create.msdn.com/en-us/resources/downloads

You can also read this post on AppHub, someone else had had the same problem as you:

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/57651/352828.aspx